# I am not properly mutate the state of my redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating a search functionality in my application with the help of redux. But it is not working as expected.

My initial state looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
  //some other state data
    locationSummaries: [],
}
```

My reducer function to update this **locationSummaries** array is given as:

```
const updateLocationSummaries = (state, action) => {
      state.locationSummaries = [...action.payload];
    },
```

My function to filter the array based on input search is given as:

```
 const handleInputSearch = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const searchText = value.toLowerCase().trim();
    let filteredLocations = locationSummaries.filter((locationSummary) =>
      locationSummary.locationName.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchText)
    );
    dispatch(updateLocationSummaries(filteredLocations));
  };
```

Here **searchText** is the value that I am entering in the input text box

So in this, I am filtering the array lists when I am typing the text in the input search box.

After dispatching the filtered lists, my state is getting updated. But my **locationSummaries** array is eventually getting emptied. So what am I doing wrong in this scenario?

Comment: Please show the full reducer. At this point is is not clear if you use legacy Redux (where you have to write immutable logic) or modern Redux (where an assignment with `=` would be okay).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you update the same array.

1. Keep another array to store filtered values.

```
const initialState = {
  //some other state data
  locationSummaries: [],
  filteredLocationSummaries: [],
}
```

2. Update that `locationSummaries` array in the ation.

```
const updateLocationSummaries = (state, action) => {
      state.filteredLocationSummaries = [...action.payload];
},
```

3. In the component use `filteredLocationSummaries` to render the filtered values.

Comment: @Swapnil Chaturvedi, check this out !!

Answer (score 0):

The better answer here is **don't keep the filtered values in state**.

Instead, **keep the *original* data in Redux, keep a *description* of how to filter the data in the component, and do the filtering while rendering**:

```js
const items = useSelector(state => state.some.items);
const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState('');

const filteredItems = useMemo(() => {
  if (!filterText) return items;
  return items.filter(item => item.includes(filterText);
}, [items, filterText]);
```